# ORACLE updating records with 1 to many table relationship in a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I'm stuck, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I need some help!

Given a table **PERSON** which maps to a person:

```
create table person
(
    ID integer,
    registration_number varchar(9),
    primary_number varchar(9),
    women_act varchar(1)
);
```

Given a table **CONSOLIDATED_NUMBERS** which specifies a mapping between multiple entries from PERSON:

```
create table consolidated_numbers
(
    SECONDARY_NUMBER varchar(9),
    person_id integer
);
```

Given a table **TRANSACTION_HISTORY** which keeps a record of all activity associated with a given person from the PERSON table (note, reason column below, lines up with valid_code above)

```
create table history_transaction
(
    reason varchar(2),
    person_id integer,
    type_id integer,
    action_date date
);
```

```
    insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values(132, '000000001', null);
    insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values (151, '000000002', '000000001');
```

```
insert into consolidated_numbers (SECONDARY_NUMBER,person_id) values ('000000002', 132);
```

```
insert into history_transaction (reason,person_id,type_id,action_date) values ('A1', 132, 1420, DATE '2019-01-01');
```

Given a table **CODE** which tracks valid codes:

```
    create table code
    (
        valid_code varchar(2)
    );
```

```
    insert into code (valid_code) values ('A1');
    insert into code (valid_code) values ('T1');
    insert into code (valid_code) values ('N2');
```

The desire is for when a personX from PERSON does something such that it updates the TRANSACTION_HISTORY table, then all people in PERSON associated with personX, as mapped in table CONSOLIDATED_NUMBERS, should be updated to have their women_act column set to X.

```
    create or replace TRIGGER trans_hist_trg
        AFTER
    INSERT OR
    UPDATE OF reason
        ON history_transaction
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
    v_exists   VARCHAR2
    (1);
    v_valid    code.valid_code%TYPE;
    v_person_id     person.id%TYPE;

    BEGIN
        IF(INSERTING) THEN
        v_person_id := :NEW.person_id;
    ELSE
        v_person_id := :OLD.person_id;
    END
    IF;
    BEGIN
        SELECT women_act
        INTO  v_exists
        FROM person
        WHERE id = v_person_id;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
           v_exists := NULL;
    END;

    SELECT valid_code
    INTO v_valid
    FROM code
    WHERE valid_code = :NEW.reason;

    IF v_exists IS NULL AND :NEW.type_id IN
    (120,140,1420,1440,160,180,150,1520,1540,1560) THEN
    IF :NEW.reason NOT IN
    ('T1','A1') OR
    (:NEW.reason IN
    ('T1','A1') AND :NEW.action_date >= '01-JAN-00') THEN
    BEGIN
        SELECT valid_code
        INTO v_valid
        FROM code
        WHERE valid_code = :NEW.reason;
        EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    v_exists := null;
    END;
    IF v_valid IS NOT NULL THEN
    UPDATE person
                SET women_act = 'X'
                WHERE (id = v_person_id
        OR id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM person
        WHERE registration_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT SECONDARY_NUMBER
        FROM consolidated_numbers
        WHERE person_id = v_person_id)));
    END IF;
   END IF;    
  END IF;            
 
END trans_hist_trg;
```

```
   ---validate records
    select * from person;
    select * from consolidated_numbers;
    select * from history_transaction;
    select * from code;

    --update reocord to activate trigger 
    update history_transaction
      set reason = 'A1'
      where person_id = 132;

    --should update 2 records (132 and 151 with x. Initially they were null)
    select * from `person`;
```

My challenge right now is to set the banner to all the consolidated numbers. Right now if I set the banner to a primary number, the banner will show on all the secondary numbers; however if I set the banner on the secondary number, it will not show on the primary.

Please help!

Comment: Try changing `:NEW.action_date >= '01-JAN-00'` to `:NEW.action_date >= TO_DATE('01-JAN-2000', 'dd-mon-yyyy')`, in the first instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a trigger for this.  Most of the conditions that you've coded into the nested IFs (of your trigger) can probably be done via foreign key constraints and check constraints.  Also, you do not need to store the 'X' for WOMAN_ACT anywhere, as it is a "derived value" ie you can obtain or generate it when querying your data.  Maybe the following example (based on your original tables and data) will help you to find a solution.  Please read the comments in the code.

**DDL code**

```
create table person (
  id number primary key
, registration_number varchar2(9) unique
, primary_number varchar2(9)
-- , women_act varchar2(1)   <- not needed!
); 
  
create table consolidated_numbers (
  secondary_number varchar2(9) references person( registration_number )
, person_id number references person( id )
); 

create table code (
  valid_code varchar2(2) primary key
);

-- CHECK constraint added to allow only certain TYPE_IDs
create table history_transaction (
  reason varchar2(2) references code( valid_code ) -- valid REASONSs enforced by FK constraint
, person_id number references person( id )
, type_id number check (
    type_id in (
      120, 140, 1420, 1440, 160, 180, 150, 1520, 1540, 1560  -- only allow these type_ids
    )
  )
, action_date date
);
```

**Test data**

```
-- INSERT your initial test data
begin
  insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values(132, '000000001', null);
  insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values (151, '000000002', '000000001');
  insert into consolidated_numbers (SECONDARY_NUMBER,person_id) values ('000000002', 132);
  insert into code (valid_code) values ('A1');
  insert into code (valid_code) values ('T1');
  insert into code (valid_code) values ('N2');
  insert into history_transaction (reason,person_id,type_id,action_date)
    values ('A1', 132, 1420, DATE '2019-01-01');
  commit ;
end;
/
```

The following VIEW will pick up person_ids from the HISTORY_TRANSACTION tables, add and 'X' to every one of them, and also pick up all persons who are "associated" with (or: mapped to) these ids from CONSOLIDATED_NUMBERS, and also add an 'X' to their ids. (Side note: it seems that your PERSON table contains a recursive relationship, so one could write a recursive query.  However, you will have a reason for modelling the CONSOLIDATED_NUMBERS table, so we will be using a JOIN here.)

**VIEW**

```
create or replace view personx
as
with PID as (
  select distinct person_id
  from history_transaction
)
select person_id, 'X' as woman_act  -- [Q1] all person_ids from history_transaction
from PID
union
select P.id, 'X' as woman_act       -- [Q2] all person_ids associated with ids from Q1
from person P
  join consolidated_numbers C
    on P.registration_number = C.secondary_number
    and C.person_id in (
      select person_id from PID
    )
;

-- with your initial test data, we get:
select * from personx ;
+---------+---------+
|PERSON_ID|WOMAN_ACT|
+---------+---------+
|132      |X        |
|151      |X        |
+---------+---------+
```

Now, let's remove/add some data, and run a few tests (see also: [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=91e3df68f77371e80714bd631f1556a9)):

```
-- test 1
delete from history_transaction ;
select * from personx ;
-- result: no rows selected -> OK

-- test 2
insert into history_transaction (reason,person_id,type_id,action_date) 
  values ('A1', 132, 1420, DATE '2019-01-01');
  
select * from personx ;
+---------+---------+
|PERSON_ID|WOMAN_ACT|
+---------+---------+
|132      |X        |
|151      |X        |
+---------+---------+

-- test 3: add more associations
begin   
-- new: person 345 associated with person 132
  insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values (345, '000000345', '000000001');
  insert into consolidated_numbers (SECONDARY_NUMBER,person_id) values ('000000345', 132);
  commit ;
end ;
/

select * from personx ;
+---------+---------+
|PERSON_ID|WOMAN_ACT|
+---------+---------+
|132      |X        |
|151      |X        |
|345      |X        |
+---------+---------+
```

Another test before we go into more details:

```
-- test 4
-- add more associations 
-- no entry in history_transactions for person(id) 1000        
begin   
  insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values(1000, '000000777', null);
  insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values (2000, '000000778', '000000777');
  insert into consolidated_numbers (SECONDARY_NUMBER,person_id) values ('000000778', 1000);
  commit ;
end ;
/   

-- output must be the same as before -> result OK
select * from personx ;
+---------+---------+
|PERSON_ID|WOMAN_ACT|
+---------+---------+
|132      |X        |
|151      |X        |
|345      |X        |
+---------+---------+
```

**JOIN** the view to the person table

```
-- test 5
-- add an entry from person 1000 into the history_transaction table
insert into history_transaction (reason,person_id,type_id,action_date) 
    values ('N2', 1000, 1420, sysdate);  

select * from personx ;
+---------+---------+
|PERSON_ID|WOMAN_ACT|
+---------+---------+
|132      |X        |
|151      |X        |
|345      |X        |
|1000     |X        |
|2000     |X        |
+---------+---------+

-- test 5: show more details
select P.id, P.registration_number, P.primary_number, PX.woman_act
from personx PX right join person P on PX.person_id = P.id ;

+----+-------------------+--------------+---------+
|ID  |REGISTRATION_NUMBER|PRIMARY_NUMBER|WOMAN_ACT|
+----+-------------------+--------------+---------+
|132 |000000001          |NULL          |X        |
|151 |000000002          |000000001     |X        |
|345 |000000345          |000000001     |X        |
|1000|000000777          |NULL          |X        |
|2000|000000778          |000000777     |X        |
+----+-------------------+--------------+---------+
```

The outer join is needed for PERSON_IDs that have no corresponding rows in the HISTORY_TRANSACTION table eg

```
-- test 6
-- add more associations
-- no entry in history_transactions for person(id) 10000!
begin
  insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values(10000, '000007777', null);
  insert into person (ID,registration_number,primary_number) values (20000, '000007778', '000007777');
  insert into consolidated_numbers (SECONDARY_NUMBER,person_id) values ('000007778', 10000);
  commit ;
end ;
/

-- after TEST 6 data have been inserted:
select P.id, P.registration_number, P.primary_number, PX.woman_act
from personx PX right join person P on PX.person_id = P.id ;

+-----+-------------------+--------------+---------+
|ID   |REGISTRATION_NUMBER|PRIMARY_NUMBER|WOMAN_ACT|
+-----+-------------------+--------------+---------+
|132  |000000001          |NULL          |X        |
|151  |000000002          |000000001     |X        |
|345  |000000345          |000000001     |X        |
|1000 |000000777          |NULL          |X        |
|2000 |000000778          |000000777     |X        |
|20000|000007778          |000007777     |NULL     |
|10000|000007777          |NULL          |NULL     |
+-----+-------------------+--------------+---------+
```

**EDIT**

If - as stated in your comment - you must store a value in the WOMAN_ACT column (although it apparently is a "derived value"), you could write a package that contains procedures for all required DML operations - still without using a trigger.  However, without knowing the full story it is hard to decide whether this would be the best way forward.  The following example uses a small package containing procedures for setting WOMAN_ACT values of the PERSON table, and a trigger that fires after INSERTs/UPDATEs(table: HISTORY_TRANSACTIONS). DBfiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=597654f6dcf2c69a30cabba6529f1442).

**PERSON table**

```
create table person (
  id number primary key
, registration_number varchar2(9) unique
, primary_number varchar2(9)
, woman_act varchar2(1) check ( woman_act in ( null, 'X' ) )
);
-- all other tables: same as before
```

**PACKAGE**

```
create or replace package pxpkg
is
  -- find out whether a certain id (table: PERSON) is a "parent" or a "child"
  function isparent( id_ number ) return boolean ;
  -- set 'X' values: id_ is a "parent"
  procedure setx_parentchildren( id_ number ) ;
  -- set 'X' values: id_ is a "child" 
  procedure setx_childsiblings( id_ number ) ;
end pxpkg ;
/
```

**PACKAGE BODY**

```
create or replace package body pxpkg
is
  function isparent( id_ number )
  return boolean
  is
    secondarynumbers pls_integer := 0 ;
  begin
    select count(*) into secondarynumbers
    from consolidated_numbers
    where person_id = id_ ;
    if secondarynumbers = 0 then
      return false ;
    else
      return true ;
    end if ;
  end isparent ;
--
  procedure setx_parentchildren ( id_ number )
  is
  begin
    update person
    set woman_act = 'X'
    where id in ( 
      select id from person where id = id_ -- parent id
      union
      select id from person 
      where primary_number = ( 
        select registration_number from person where id = id_ -- parent id
      )
    ) ;
  end setx_parentchildren ;
--
  procedure setx_childsiblings ( id_ number )
  is
  begin
    update person
    set woman_act = 'X'
    where id in ( 
      with PID as (
        select id, primary_number from person
        where id = id_                    -- current id
          and primary_number is not null  -- child ids only
      )
      select id from PID
      union
      select id 
      from person 
      where registration_number in ( select primary_number from PID )
         or primary_number in ( select primary_number from PID )
    ) ;
  end setx_childsiblings ;
end pxpkg ;
/
```

**TRIGGER**

```
create or replace trigger pxtrigger
after insert or update on history_transaction
for each row
begin
  if pxpkg.isparent( :new.person_id ) then
    pxpkg.setx_parentchildren( :new.person_id )  ;
  else
    pxpkg.setx_childsiblings( :new.person_id )  ;
  end if ;
end pxtrigger ;
/
```

TESTING: see [DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=597654f6dcf2c69a30cabba6529f1442)

Comment: its a requirement to store `WOMAN_ACT` field Into the table.

Comment: I like your approach,  The `woman_act` its a must, what will be the change in your code?

Comment: @MarianaLungu - I have added an example that will write values into the WOMAN_ACT column of the PERSON table.

Comment: I can't use a view for my problem It has to be a trigger, the women_act field has to be stored in the table. There are single records that exist and have that field. The view that you provided could work well for other cases but not in my case. Thanks

Comment: Have you actually looked at the DBfiddle?  The WOMAN_ACT data _is_ stored in the PERSON table.  If you don't want to use the view, just put its code into the procedures (I have only kept it in the EDIT so that it is easier to see what the procedures are doing.)  Also, the code in the EDIT _relies_ on the trigger ie it would not work without it.

Comment: Please have a look at this: just a trigger and 2 procedures.  No view.  WOMAN_ACT data stored in PERSON.  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4e3692cff5fc6843152379007137c9c2

Comment: thank you for helping! I just looked and tested, when I set the flag for a person it should set the flag for the related (associated) ids, but the query you provided it sets the flag for all the ids that have associations, which is not good. Plus when I delete a transaction history it should not remove the flag, but right now it removes the flag from all the ids.

Comment: You just need to {1} tweak the SELECT statement inside the procedures and {2} remove some lines from the trigger.  Look at this version: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a247e5f231de52bc7a2c5516f05032a3

Comment: sorry but we don't need to remove, because the way the app is designed, they are able to remove/delete the banner from the UI, it's coded in JAVA. The women_act field is either NULL or 'X'. The exiting trigger sets the banner for a single record based on different code(reason) as stated on the question. My current struggle is not being able to set the banner for all consolidated records. The business requirement is to have the banner on single or consolidated records if the transaction history changes for that person.

Comment: this piece of code `WHERE (id = v_person_id
        OR id IN (SELECT DISTINCT id
        FROM person
        WHERE registration_number IN (SELECT DISTINCT SECONDARY_NUMBER
        FROM consolidated_numbers
        WHERE person_id = v_person_id)))`  it is working if I set the flag on the primary - it sets the banner for all the secondary, but If I try to set on the secondary it does not set the flag for the primary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219425/discussion-between-stefan-and-mariana-lungu).