# BULK COLLECT in a trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

I need to create a trigger that updates a column in a table based on a transaction that happens in another table. Is there a way to use BULK COLLECT on joining two tables?

I need to collect data multiple times, is it possible to use BULK COLLECT inside another BULK COLLECT?

HERE is my existing trigger

```
create or replace trigger trans_hist_trg
AFTER  INSERT OR UPDATE OF reason ON transaction_history
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE     

    v_exists   VARCHAR2(1);
    v_valid   code.valid_code%TYPE;
    v_person_id     person.id%TYPE;
     TYPE Anumber_Type is TABLE of person.registration_number%TYPE INDEX BY binary_INTEGER;
    v_NumberList Anumber_Type;
    v_primaryAnumber    person.primary_number%TYPE;
     v_secondaryAnumber  consolidated_numbers.secondary_number%TYPE;
    v_anumber   person.registration_number%TYPE;

BEGIN
    IF(INSERTING) THEN
        v_person_id := :NEW.person_id;
    ELSE
        v_person_id := :OLD.person_id;
    END IF;
    
  BEGIN
        SELECT p.registration_number, p.primary_number, c.secondary_number INTO v_anumber, v_primaryAnumber, v_secondaryAnumber
        FROM person p
        LEFT JOIN consolidated_numbers c ON p.id = c.person_id WHERE p.id = v_person_id;
     END;
    BEGIN
        SELECT women_act INTO  v_exists
        FROM person
        WHERE id = v_person_id;
        EXCEPTION
        WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
           v_exists := NULL;
    END;
    IF v_exists IS NULL AND :NEW.type_id IN (10,20,30,40,50) THEN
        IF :NEW.reason NOT IN ('A1','B1') OR (:NEW.reason IN ('A1','B1') AND :NEW.action_date >= '01-JAN-00') THEN
           BEGIN
            SELECT valid_code INTO v_valid 
            FROM  code
            WHERE valid_code = :NEW.reason;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
                    v_exists := null;
         END;
            IF v_valid IS NOT NULL THEN
               SELECT CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM code WHERE valid_code = v_valid)
                    THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END INTO v_exists FROM dual;
            END IF;
            IF v_exists = 'Y' THEN 
                select registration_number BULK COLLECT into v_NumberList 
                FROM person where (registration_number=v_primaryAnumber OR
                                    registration_number=v_anumber OR
                                     registration_number=v_secondaryAnumber OR
                                     primary_number= v_secondaryAnumber OR
                                    primary_number=v_anumber OR
                                    primary_number=v_primaryAnumber ) and (primary_number IS NOT NULL or primary_number <>'000000');
            ELSE
            select registration_number BULK COLLECT into v_NumberList 
            FROM person where (registration_number=v_primaryAnumber OR
                                registration_number=v_anumber OR
                                registration_number=v_secondaryAnumber OR
                                primary_number=v_anumber OR
                                primary_number=v_secondaryAnumber OR
                                primary_number=v_primaryAnumber OR
                                primary_number IS NULL);
            END IF;
            FOR indx IN 1 .. v_NumberList.COUNT
            LOOP
                update person set women_act = 'X' 
                where registration_number=v_NumberList(indx) and (women_act<>'X' or women_act IS NULL);
            END LOOP;
                update person set women_act = 'X'
                where registration_number=v_anumber and (women_act<>'X' or women_act IS NULL);
        END IF;
    END IF;
    
    mmm
END trans_hist_trg;
```

I need to make this block of code to be my main outer loop to iterate through all the numbers. But I'm unsure how. Please help.

```
SELECT p.registration_number, p.primary_number, c.secondary_number INTO v_anumber, v_primaryAnumber, v_secondaryAnumber
        FROM person p
        LEFT JOIN consolidated_numbers c ON p.id = c.person_id WHERE p.id = v_person_id;
```

Thank you!

Comment: _"Is there a way to use BULK COLLECT on joining two tables?_" Yes. _" is it possible to use BULK COLLECT inside another BULK COLLECT?"_ No. You can iterate over a collection multiple times though. You can also create a new collection that's a copy of the first collection. To give you a proper answer though the community is going to need more information, and preferably some code (working or not working) that explains exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Ben I updated the question, please help!

Comment: BTW, these horrible "bulk collect" and forr-loops in the existing trigger can be replaced by the simple UPDATE statement. I think you should start from refactoring the existing code first instead of putthing another nested "bulk collect" there.

Comment: @krokodilko I understand but I don't know another way to grab all the associated records from both tables. Please take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63241108/oracle-updating-records-with-1-to-many-table-relationship-in-a-trigger

Comment: Your first SELECT will fail (and end the trigger execution) if person does not exist. Comparing a DATE with a string (`>= '01-JAN-00'`) is the worst thing you can do - an even with 2-digits year.

Comment: Condition `primary_number IS NOT NULL or primary_number <>'000000'` is useless, i. E. redundant